# Why does jsdom set my attribute *values* to all lowercase?

Tags: jsdom

here is sample code. running in webstorm.
    "jsdom": "^13.2.0"
    node 10.15.0

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;

dom = new JSDOM("");
uri = "file://testResource/test.js"
const script = dom.window.document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.async = true;
script.setAttribute("src",uri);

console.log(`loading script ${script.src}`); //loading script file://testresource/test.js
console.log(`loading script ${uri}`); //loading script file://testResource/test.js
```

Note the case change on the word Resource.
I understand that the attribute names are not case sensitive, but the values should be, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your URI is written the `testResource` part is a hostname. Host names are case-insensitive and [URI Generic Syntax (RFC3986)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) states:

> Although host is case-insensitive, producers and normalizers should use lowercase for registered names and hexadecimal addresses for the sake of uniformity, while only using uppercase letters for percent-encodings.

What is going on here is that JSDOM is normalizing the hostname, and in doing so is making it lowercase. (BTW, type the same URI in Chrome and you'll see Chrome does the same.)

If your URI was meant to not have a hostname, then you need to write it like this:

```
file:///testResource/test.js
```

Note the additional slash before `testResource`. This URI has an empty hostname. When the hostname is empty, `localhost` is the understood host.